# HTML5 Canvas- moving a star across the canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am very new to HTML5 Canvas. I have been working on building shapes however, I cannot get a star that I created to move in a "shooting star-fashion". If you could help me get the star to move, at least across the screen, that would be so helpful.

Here is the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawStar(cx, cy, spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius) {
    var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
    var x = cx;
    var y = cy;
    var step = Math.PI / spikes;

    ctx.strokeSyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
    for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y)
        rot += step

        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x, y)
        rot += step
    }
    ctx.lineTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth=1;
    ctx.strokeStyle='#0797c4';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillStyle='#0797c4';
    ctx.fill();

}

drawStar(75, 100, 5, 30, 15);
```

Here is the Codepen:
http://codepen.io/codingexperiments/pen/QbVyqE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `requestAnimationFrame` (rAF) as an animation loop to move your star.**

The typical rAF loop works like this:

```
// start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){

    // change the x,y position of your star

    // clear the canvas and draw your star at the new x,y

    // request another frame

}
```

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;

// for efficiency, create the star once on an in-memory canvas
var star=makeStarCanvas(31, 31, 5, 30, 15);

// the star's current x position
var x=0;

ctx.drawImage(star,x,110);


$('#go').click(function(){
    // start the star at x=0
    x=0;
    // use requestAnimationFrame to animate the star
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);    
});


function animate(time){

    // move the star rightward
    x+=1;
    // move the star vertically in a sine wave pattern
    var y=Math.sin(x/(cw/4))*-100+110;

    // draw the star canvas onto the main canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(star,x,y);

    // continue animating if the star hasn't moved off the canvas
    if(x<cw){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

}

// make an in-memory canvas with a star drawing
function makeStarCanvas(cx, cy, spikes, outerRadius, innerRadius) {
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
    var x = cx;
    var y = cy;
    var step = Math.PI / spikes;

    cctx.strokeSyle = "#000";
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.moveTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
    for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
        cctx.lineTo(x, y)
        rot += step

        x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
        y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
        cctx.lineTo(x, y)
        rot += step
    }
    cctx.lineTo(cx, cy - outerRadius)
    cctx.closePath();
    cctx.lineWidth=1;
    cctx.strokeStyle='#0797c4';
    cctx.stroke();
    cctx.fillStyle='#0797c4';
    cctx.fill();
    return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='go'>Animate</button>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```